# How to change finder search criteria defaults?

Tags: finder

In my MacBook if I add the search criteria `System Files` the default is `aren't included`, how can I change the **default permanently** to `are included`?

[image: search criteria]

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative would be EasyFind - freeware on the App Store - https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

**This is currently not possible.** You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this [here](http://apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

Comment: Thanks but not even hacking some plist file?