# How are default search criteria in Finder set

Tags: finder

Unless I change it every time, the search criteria in finder are set like this by default:
[image: like this]

Is there a way to change it? Most of the things I usually search for are *not* like the ones filtered in.

I have seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145302/how-to-change-finder-search-criteria-defaults). The difference here is I want to eliminate the search criteria completely.

Comment: How are you initiating a search in Finder?

Comment: Cmd+F shortcut @grgarside

Answer (score 1):

As long as [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is disabled in your machine, you should be able to edit `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/default_smart.plist` to change the default search criteria.

Try this:

1. Make your desired default search in Finder and then save it like you would normally save your search.
2. Go to the saved searches folder (unless you saved it somewhere else) `~/Library/Saved Searches/`

   - In newer OS versions the Library folder inside the user folder should be hidden, so just use the `Go to Folder` method in the top menu in Finder `Go > Go to folder...` and paste the path there.
3. Open your `.savedSearch` file with `TextEdit.app`
4. Copy & Paste all the contents of that file to that `default_smart.plist` file: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/default_smart.plist`

   - You can locate this file with the `Go to folder...` method as well.
   - You may want to make sure you got a copy of that original `default_smart.plist` beforehand...

Then test out the search.